# Using part of a field value in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Is it possible to use only several starting characters of a field value as a base of case statement in a SQL Server stored procedure? 
For example, I need to update a field in a table according to the first three characters in another field of the same table:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Field1 = CASE 
             WHEN ??? = 'vl1' THEN '01'
             WHEN ??? = 'vl2' THEN '02'
             WHEN ??? = 'vl3' THEN '03' 
             '''''
END
```

How could I use the first three characters of a `Field2` value instead of `???` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Column1 = CASE SUBSTRING(Column2,1,3)
             WHEN 'vl1' THEN '01'
             WHEN 'vl2' THEN '02'
             WHEN 'vl3' THEN '03' 
             '''''
END
```

(I've switched to a [simple CASE expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) since that's all we need here, and switched terminology too)

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET Column1 = CASE left(Column2,3) 
      WHEN 'vl1' THEN '01'              
      WHEN 'vl2' THEN '02'              
      WHEN 'vl3' THEN '03'               
      ''''' 
END
```

Comment: @El Ronnoco - SQL Server supports `LEFT` and `RIGHT`

Comment: yes it does and you can do cool things like left(RIGHT(colA,8),3) lets say you had (013)661-1525 as a phone number and wanted the area code Left(Right(phoneNumber,len(phoneNumber)),3)

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to worry about one digit you can use

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Column1 = '0' + SUBSTRING(Column2,3,1)
```

Comment: Values in my example are just sample ones, nevertheless +1 for the useful approach

Answer (score 0):

*UPDATED - ouch, thanks for the tip Damien!*

You can also set up a mapping table to do a merge instead of a row by row case
(2005+)

```
;with map(old,new) as (
    select 'vl1', '01' union all
    select 'vl2', '02' union all
    select 'vl3', '03'
)
UPDATE Table1
SET Field1 = Map.new
From Table1
Left Join Map on Map.old=Left(Table1.Field,3)
```

Comment: I think you've put your `LEFT` call in the wrong place (should be in the join condition)

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of a mapping CTE (@cyberkiwi) but not so much the old style proprietary code (and `new` and `old` are reserved words).

Here's a rewrite:

```
WITH Map (old_field2, new_field1)
     AS
     (
      SELECT old_field2, new_field1
        FROM (
              VALUES ('vl1', '01'), 
                     ('vl2', '02'), 
                     ('vl3', '03')
             ) AS Map (old_field2, new_field1)
     )
MERGE INTO Table1
USING Map AS source
   ON Table1.Field2 LIKE source.old_field2 + '%'
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE 
      SET Field1 = source.new_field1;
```